# How to profile a .Net Core app on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, profiling

How do you profile a asp.net core running on Mac OSX? Is there a profiling tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. .Net Core 3 just launched a Profile tool called [`dotnet-trace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-trace) for tracing and [`dotnet-dump`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-dump) for dumping a process.

PS: ignore @charlybones comment, it does work as expected

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as an answer. It is currently not supported on Mac OS X

Comment: what is not supported on Mac osx? the tools I mentioned above do work on Mac osx and I have been using them on a daily basis now

Comment: dotnet-dump is not supported on macOS. It’s the first thing that appears in the Microsoft website when you click on that link.

Comment: I bumped into this today, I'm not sure what was the case on January this year, but at least June 2020, the above-mentioned tools are supported on macOS:

`$ dotnet-trace --version
3.1.120604+97218bff6a14e60360862529b09b687789cc1279

$ dotnet-dump --version
3.1.122203+2c03f4eb39cfa9fe281204b125203ff79627ca02`

Comment: @charlybones per last comment it does work... I always use the alpha version, perhaps that's why it always worked for me